# Unable to mount decrypted image

Tags: filesystems, mount, fsck, cryptsetup, dm-crypt

I have an encrypted image (ext4) that can be mounted perfectly on my Raspberry Pi but not on my (L)Ubuntu VM. The following commands work perfectly on the Pi:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen stuff.iso img
sudo mount /dev/mapper/img /media/img/
```

If I make take a copy of that image to my (L)Ubuntu VM and invoke the same `mount` command, I get the errors:

```
mount: /dev/mapper/img is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/mapper/img: can't read superblock
```

I can't run `fsck` on it either:

```
$ sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/mapper/img 
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
fsck.ext4: Operation not permitted while trying to open /dev/mapper/img
You must have r/w access to the filesystem or be root
```

Can copies of encrypted images not be made? The MD5s of the copy and the original match.

Here's `ls -l /media/`

`drwxr-xr-x  2 gp root 4096 Nov 12 11:37 img`

Here's more output:

```
$ ls -l /dev/mapper/img 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov 13 15:16 /dev/mapper/img -> ../dm-0
```

Comment: The output of ``ls -l /dev/mapper/img`` might be useful. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @G-Man Sure. I've added that now.

Comment: If you encrypt an image on one system and then try to mount it on another without decrypting, getting errors would be the expected behavior? Otherwise what is the point in encrypting the media in the first place?

Comment: @RamanSailopal It is decrypted with `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen stuff.iso img` though.